# Parsing JValue to either JObject or JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there a nice way to get a json value, using `var myValue = json["prop"]` and insert it to a common object/interface? The value could be a `json {}` or an `array []`. I know I can insert them to a `JObject` and `JArray`, but is there a common object?

I also want to know (maybe the same answer to the above),  if I can parse json from string, when again, I don't know if it's an array or an object.

Comment: You need to `deserialize` your `string` into Json using Json.net.  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CommonObject>(string)` . As long as the string is in correct `json` format you can parse it to `json` easily using the above code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `JToken` type is a common base type for `JObject` and `JArray`. It is what `json["prop"]` would return, and if you had a `JToken` of either type, then you could set `json["prop"] = token`.